# How to add a custom Button in AntD pagination to download a report?

Tags: reactjs, pagination, antd

I want to add download button in pagination and I want to allow download table data as an excel file. Is it possible to add and render a custom button in Antd pagination. Here with I attached an image to show what I am going to archive.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `showTotal` of Pagination props like below:

```js
import { Pagination, Button } from "antd";
import DownloadOutlined from "@ant-design/icons/DownloadOutlined";

// render Pagination
<Pagination
  total={25}
  showSizeChanger
  showTotal={(total) => (
    <div>
      {`Total ${total} items`}
      <Button
        type="primary"
        icon={<DownloadOutlined />}
        style={{ marginLeft: 8 }}
      />
    </div>
  )}
/>
```